# Vanilla JS DOM manipulation (inconsistent rendering of nodes)

Tags: javascript, dom

Usually my page looks like this:

[image]

Take note of the scroll bar on right most part of the image.

PROBLEM: sometimes the `school logo card` would appear at the bottom of the page whenever I go back and forth with `Home` tab and `About` tab buttons on the left.
There is no consistent count every time I switch between `Home` and `About` on whenever the `school logo card` would appear at the bottom.
it looks like this:

The `school logo card` would be rendered after the `home carousel card`

[image]

My js code:

```
const pageContent = document.getElementById('page-content')

handleLogoForm()


//handles form submission for school logo card
function handleLogoForm(){
    var logoform = document.getElementById('logo-form')
    logoform.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        let input = document.getElementById('inputGroupFile02');

        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('image',input.files[0]);

        var url = "/web-content/api/changelogo/"

        fetch(url,{
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
            },
            body:data
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(function(data){
            updateLogo()
            e.target.reset()
            handleLogoForm.call(this);
            logo = document.getElementById('logo-div')
            logo.innerHTML = ""
            logo.innerHTML = `<img src="${data.image}" alt="no image provided" style="max-width: 7rem; max-height: 7rem;">`
        })
    })
}


// Getting Home Page Contents

function getLogoCard(){
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/web-content/api/changelogo/"

    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function(data){

        // constructing nodes

        // create div card parent node
        var card = document.createElement('div')
        card.classList.add('card')
        // cardBody child
        var cardBody = document.createElement('div')
        cardBody.classList.add('card-body')

        var header = document.createElement('h5')
        header.innerText = 'School Logo'
        var label1 = document.createElement('small')
        label1.innerText = 'On display: '

        var image = document.createElement('img')
        image.src = data[0].image
        image.id = 'img'
        image.classList.add('card-img-top')
        image.style.maxWidth = '10rem'
        image.style.maxHeight = '10rem'

        var form = document.createElement('form')
        form.action = '/web-content/api/changelogo/'
        form.method = 'POST'
        form.enctype ='multipart/form-data'
        form.id ='logo-form'
        form.style.display = 'inline'

        var csrftokennode = document.createElement('input')
        csrftokennode.type = 'hidden'
        csrftokennode.value = csrftoken 

        var inputGroup = document.createElement('div')
        inputGroup.classList.add('input-group', 'mb-3')

        var imageField = document.createElement('input')
        imageField.type = 'file'
        imageField.name = 'image'
        imageField.classList.add('form-control')
        imageField.required = true
        imageField.id = 'inputGroupFile02'

        var uploadButton = document.createElement('button')
        uploadButton.type = 'submit'
        uploadButton.classList.add('input-group-text')
        uploadButton.for = 'inputGroupFile02'
        uploadButton.innerText = 'Upload'

        var label = document.createElement('label')
        label.for = 'inputGroupFile02'
        label.innerText = 'Change:'


        // combine elemnts together

        card.append(cardBody)
        cardBody.append(header)
        cardBody.append(label1)
        cardBody.append(image)
        cardBody.append(document.createElement('br'))
        cardBody.append(label)
        cardBody.append(form)
        form.append(csrftokennode)
        form.append(imageField)
        form.append(uploadButton)



        pageContent.append(card)

        handleLogoForm()

    })
}


function getCarouselCard(){
    var url = "/web-content/api/home-carousel/"

    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function(data){

        var carouselItems = data

        // // constructing nodes
        var card = document.createElement('div')
        card.id = 'carousel'
        card.classList.add('card')
        var cardBody = document.createElement('div')
        cardBody.id = 'card-body'
        cardBody.classList.add('card-body')
        var header = document.createElement('h5')
        header.innerText = 'Home Carousel'
        var onDisplay = document.createElement('small')
        onDisplay.innerText = 'On display: '
        var cardImage = document.createElement('img')
        cardImage.classList.add('card-img-top')
        cardImage.alt = '...'
        cardImage.style.maxWidth = '15rem'
        cardImage.style.maxHeight = '15rem'
        var cardLabel = document.createElement('small')
        cardLabel.innerText = ""
        var cardContent = document.createElement('small')
        cardContent.innerText = ""
        var iconGroup = document.createElement('span')
        iconGroup.style.fontSize = '20px'
        var trashIconSpan = document.createElement('span')
        trashIconSpan.style.color = 'red'
        var trashIcon = document.createElement('i')
        trashIcon.classList.add('fas', 'fa-trash-alt')
        var editIconSpan = document.createElement('span')
        editIconSpan.style.color = 'brown'
        var editIcon = document.createElement('i')
        editIcon.classList.add('far', 'fa-edit')

        // construct nodes

        card.append(cardBody)
        cardBody.append(header)
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            cardBody.append(onDisplay)
            cardImage.src = data[i].image
            cardBody.append(cardImage)
            cardBody.innerHTML += '<br>'
            cardBody.append(cardLabel)
            cardLabel.innerText = data[i].label
            cardBody.innerHTML += '<br>'
            cardBody.append(cardContent)
            cardContent.innerText = data[i].content
            cardBody.innerHTML += '<br>'
            cardBody.append(iconGroup)
            iconGroup.append(trashIconSpan)
            trashIconSpan.append(trashIcon)
            iconGroup.append(editIconSpan)
            editIconSpan.append(editIcon)
            cardBody.innerHTML += `<br><hr>`
        }


        pageContent.append(card)

    })
}


// formsssssss
// change logo




function showHomeContent(){
    if ( document.getElementById("homeButton").className.match(/(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/) ){

    }else{
        document.getElementById('homeButton').classList.add('active')
        pageContent.innerHTML = ""
        getLogoCard()
        getCarouselCard()

    }
    if ( document.getElementById("aboutButton").className.match(/(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/) ){
        document.getElementById("aboutButton").classList.remove('active')
    }


}

function showAboutContent(){
    if ( document.getElementById("aboutButton").className.match(/(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/) ){
        return;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('aboutButton').classList.add('active')
        pageContent.innerHTML = ""
        pageContent.innerHTML += `
        this is about content
    `
    }
    if ( document.getElementById("homeButton").className.match(/(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/) ){
        document.getElementById("homeButton").classList.remove('active')
    }
    
}
```

the functions that are hooked with `Home` and `About` button on the left are `showHomeContent()` and `showAboutContent()`

Comment: The fetch calls are asynchronous so there is no guarantee what completes before the other. So you have a race condition.  If order matters, you need to rethink how you make the two calls so they come back in the correct order. Or change the code to append them in the order.

Comment: ohhh i see. Can I ask, what would be the best thing to do here for the cards to comeback in order?

Comment: promise all would be the best way to go. return the fetch call from the function call

Comment: so you mean, i should put the fetch call for `home carousel card` inside the promise of `school logo card`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you are making two fetch requests that are asynchronous and they are racing to be done first. Whoever wins the race is rendered on top.

So when you fetch the contents, use Promise All

```
Promise.all([getLogoCard(), getCarouselCard()]).then((values) => {
  values.forEach(card => pageContent.append(card));
});
```

In your functions, return the fetch call, have the fetch return the element you want to append to the document

```
function getLogoCard() {
  ...
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function(data){
      ...
      return card; 
    });
}
```

Comment: one follow up question sir, where would I put the function that will handle the form submission for each card? i got an error on console: cms.js:203 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at handleLogoForm (cms.js:203)
    at showHomeContent (cms.js:246)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM36536 :63) I updated my question for you to see the handleLogoForm() function.

Comment: So you call `handleLogoForm` after you append it.  `Promise.all([getLogoCard(), getCarouselCard()]).then((values) => { ... }).then(handleLogoForm);`

Comment: Sir @epasccarello what would I do if I need to call those functions in another function? for example I want to call `getLogoCard()` inside ot `.then` in another function? what would I do? I tried calling it simply by `.this(function(){ getLogoCard()})` but it doesn't work.